# c# changing background color of cell in dataGridView if its value changed

Tags: c#, datagrid, onchange

Hello I want to change the background color of a cell in a datagridview if its value changed.

I have written the onChange event like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Version")
        {
          //Change Background
        }
    }
```

So how do I change the value of the changed cell now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataGridViewCellEventArgs argument contains all you need here;

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Version")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    }
}
```